# django datefield migrations giving an error

Tags: python, django

This is my model I'm trying to add a date field , but when I run migrations I'm getting this error " in parse_date
match = date_re.match(value)". I have tried deleting my migrations but I'm still getting this error

```
models.py 

class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quote_choices = ( ('Movie', 'Movie'),
     ('Inspiration', 'Inspiration'), 
     ('Language', 'Language'),
     )

    quote = models.CharField(max_length =100, choices = quote_choices)

    box_choices = (('Colors', 'Colors'),
        ('Crossover', 'Crossover'),
        )
    box = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = box_choices)
    pill_choice = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    shipping_tracking = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    memo = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    status_choices = (('Received', 'Received'),
        ('Scheduled', 'Scheduled'), 
        ('Processing/Manufacturing', 'Processing/Manufacturing'),
        ('In Progress','In Progress'),
        )
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 100, choices = status_choices, default="In Progress")
    manu_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today)
```

```
forms.py 
class OrderForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = kwargs.pop('user', None)
        super(OrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not user.is_superuser:
            self.fields.pop('status')

     
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = '__all__'
        widgets = {'manu_date': DateInput()}
        exclude = ['user','date']
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use a `ForeignKey` for the date field. Use `DateField` instead of `ForeignKey`.

And then run the following code on the command line:

1. python manage.py makemigrations
2. python manage.py migrate

And you made a mistake: `date = models.ForeignKey('date', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`. `'date'` must be Django model, not string on the code.

Comment: I'm getting error for manu_date at the end column of the model

Comment: manu_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default=datetime.date.today) let's ue it like this manu_date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

Comment: no luck it's still giving this error  " line 75, in parse_date
    match = date_re.match(value)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object "

Comment: You will have to delete some of your previous migrations after making the change.